# How to call C# .dll from a C++/CLI application?

Tags: dll, import, c++-cli, call

I'm trying to call [the LumenWorks .csv file reading library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) from a C++/CLI application and having some issues. I've added a dependancy on `LumenWorks.Framework.IO.dll` but when I try to then use the library:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using namespace Lumenworks::Framework::IO::Csv;

    // <My code definitions here>

}
```

I get a message that the compiler doesn't recognise 'Lumenworks'. Do I need to reference header files from the sources or is there a way to get the same information from the .dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try "Lumen**W**orks" (based on article on codeproject)? And add `;` at the end of line.

Comment: Accepted: Rather embarrassingly, you're right. The missing ',' was a copy/paste issue posting on SO.. but you were right about the case sensitivity!